# if $C \subset B \subset A$, and $\rho$ is a metric in $A$, and $C$ is open in $(A,\rho)$, then $C$ is open in $(B, \rho\big|_{B})$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

So, I'm trying to prove that if I have $A,B,C$ such that $C \subset B \subset A$, and $\rho$ is a metric in $A$, and $C$ is open in $(A,\rho)$, then $C$ is open in $(B, \rho\big|_{B})$.

In general, I want to see what happens if $C$ is $i)$ open in $A$, $ii)$ closed in $A$, $iii)$ open in $B$ or $iv)$ closed in $B$.

For the last case, I can prove that:

> if $C$ is closed in $(B,\rho\big|_{B})$, then $C$ is closed in $(A,\rho)$: Since being closed
> implies $B-C$ is open, then for any element $c \in B-C$, there exist an
> open ball $B_{B}(c,r)$ (with $r>0$) such that $B_{B}(c,r) \subset B-C$, then since $B\subset A$, $B-C\subset A-C$. Then, $B_{B}(c,r)
>  \subset A-C$ and that way $A-C$ is open, and $C$ is closed in $A$.

Now, for $i)$, I believe the proof is something like this:

> if $C$ is open in $A$, then for any $c\in C$, there exist some $r_{c}>0$ such that $B_{A}(c,r_c) \subset C$. Then, since $C \subset B$, $C \cap B = C$, then $C$ is open in $B$, since now consider $B_{A}(c,r_c) \cap B = B_{B}(c,r'_c)$. Then $(B_{A}(c,r_c) \cap B) \subset (C \cap B)$, this is, $B_{B}(c,r'_c) \subset C$

Are these two proofs correct?

Any hint about $ii)$ and $iii)$ would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Closed in B does not imply closed in A. Example $A=\Bbb R,B=(0,2),C=[1,2)$ (for the usual distance). So your first proof cannot be correct.

Comment: Your second proof is correct but this theorem can be easily proved more generally for an arbitrary topological space $A$ (not necessarily metrizable) and the induced topology on a subset $B$ (the open subsets of $B$ are by definition the $U\cap B$ for $U$ open subset of $A$).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks! I'll look into the first one to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Simpler counterexample: $A=\Bbb R,B=C=(0,2).$ Might be helpful while reviewing the first proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closed in $B$ does not imply closed in $A.$ Example $A=\Bbb R,B=C=(0,1)$ (for the usual distance). So your first proof cannot be correct.

Similarly, open in $B$ does not imply open in $A.$ Example $A=\Bbb R,B=C=[0,1].$

Your second proof is correct but this theorem can be easily proved more generally for an arbitrary topological space $A$
(not necessarily metrizable) and the induced topology on a subset $B$
(the open subsets of $B$
are by definition the $U∩B$
for $U$
open subset of $A$).

Similarly, in the same context, if $C$ is closed in $A$ then it is closed in $B.$